# when I press the back button in SearchResulActivity in android

Tags: android-activity

when i search the result in SearchResulActivity two or three times and I have given the launchmode singleTop in manifest file then I press the back button but back button is not giving the response in first time.

Comment: Hi welcome to stackoverflow. It is not clear what you are asking. please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: edit you question with some code